# How to put string in bundle

Tags: java

I have in my code this piece of code

```
ResourceBundle resbundle=ResourceBundle.getBundle("test", Locale.getDefault());
resbundle.getString("compileItem");
```

How to put another string in this bundle ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do this programatically then the interface does not provide any methods for modifying a bundle, so unless you find an implementation that has extensions to allow such, you cant.

If you just want to add a value to the bundle edit the text file `test.properties` (or the locale specific version if necessary) and add the line:

```
compileItem=foo
```

Answer (score 0):

[`ResourceBundle`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) objects are read-only.

They are designed for looking up locale-specific resources such as text translations, images, icons, ...

They are not meant to be written. If you want something similar to a `ResourceBundle` but writeable, then maybe a [`Properties`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) object is what you're after, or even a simple [`Map`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Comment: How to find where is "compileItem" put in resbundle ? Is that some file or what ?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on which actual implementation class you end up using. Typically that's `PropertyResourceBundle`, which means you have to add the string to the underlying property file since the class is read-only. But if you implement your own subclass of `ResourceBundle`, it could support adding entries at runtime.